# Change table contents upon dropdown list changes

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this:

```
@GetMapping("/records")
public String getRecords(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("tallies", getAllTallies(null));
    model.addAttribute("categories", getCategories());
    return "records";
}
```

`getCategories()` simply returns a list of `Category`s and `getAllTallies` simply returns a list of all `Tally`s.

If the Requested Parameter `category` is null, then it will return all tallies, regardless the category. But if it's not null, then it will return all `tallies` only from the specified `category`.

This is `getAllTallies`:

```
@GetMapping("/tallies")
@ResponseBody
public List<Tally> getAllTallies(@RequestParam(required = false) String category)
```

And then in my `records.html`:

```
<body>
<div>
    <select class="form-control" >
        <option value="0">Select Category</option>
        <option th:each="category : ${categories}" th:value="${category.id}" th:text="${category.category}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
<table cellpadding="10" border="1px">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Nominee </th>
        <th> Category </th>
        <th> Tally </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:if="${tallies.empty}">
        <td colspan="3"> No Books Available </td>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="tally : ${tallies}">
        <td><span th:text="${tally.nominee}"> Nominee </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${tally.category}"> Category </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${tally.count}"> Tally </span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

What I'm trying to do is whenever I select a new value from the dropdown list (category), then the table also changes based on the category. 
I was thinking if this was possible *without jquery or js*, only html. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to dynamically update the tables via drop down list.

Comment: You have to  make request every dropdown change ( ajax ) ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there would be no way to achieve this without `js` or `jQuery`. The thing is, `Thymeleaf` works at server side. So, once rendered, it won't be rendered again, unless your refresh your page or request a response from your server using `ajax`. In your case, a simple `ajax` would do the trick.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div>
    <select id="categories" class="form-control" >
        <option value="0">Select Category</option>
        <option th:each="category : ${categories}" th:value="${category.id}" th:text="${category.category}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
<table cellpadding="10" border="1px">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Nominee </th>
        <th> Category </th>
        <th> Tally </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tallies">
    <tr th:if="${tallies.empty}">
        <td colspan="3"> No Books Available </td>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="tally : ${tallies}">
        <td><span th:text="${tally.nominee}"> Nominee </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${tally.category}"> Category </span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${tally.count}"> Tally </span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Added ids to your categories' select and your `tbody`.

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/tallies")
@ResponseBody
public List<Tally> getAllTallies(@RequestParam(value = "category", required = false) String category)
```

Added a name to your parameter.

**jQuery**

```
$('#categories').on('change', function() {
   $.ajax({
            url: '/tallies',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                category: $(this).val();
            },
            success: function(tallies) {
                // First, let's crear our tbody.
                $('#tallies').empty();

                // Now, let's go through each one of the tallies.
                $(tallies).each( function() {
                    // Here you should add your missing fields. I am just adding one as an example.
                    $('#tallies').append('<tr><td><span>' + this.nominee + '</span></td></tr>');
                })
            }
})
```